# Recreate Gradle Scripts on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Im new to android studio and while exploring android studio i edited build.gradle, now i want to get it back to how it was at the beggining.
I would like to know if it is possible delete gradle scripts and somehow recreate them how they were at the beggining of the project.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Just delete existing ones and re import your android project in studio. It will automatically re generate all the build.gradle files for you. Give a try.

Comment: i deleted the grade files but need to know how to the re import. is here? file->new->import project..

Comment: deleting them messed up my project. terrible advice